# How do I list all file names of a ZIP archive in C++ from scratch?

Tags: c++, zip

This is the code I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void printNextFileName(std::ifstream &fs)
{
    fs.ignore(6);
    char buf[2];
    fs.read(buf,2);
    int flags=buf[0]|buf[1]<<8;
    bool hasEncryptionHeader=1&flags;
    bool hasDataDescriptor=(1<<3)&flags;

    fs.ignore(10);
    char buf2[4];
    fs.read(buf2,4);
    long size=buf2[0]|buf2[1]<<8|buf2[2]<<16|buf2[3]<<24;

    fs.ignore(4);
    char buf3[2];
    fs.read(buf3,2);
    int fileNameLength=buf3[0]|buf3[1]<<8;

    char buf4[2];
    fs.read(buf4,2);
    int extraFieldLength=buf4[0]|buf4[1]<<8;

    char buf5[fileNameLength];
    fs.read(buf5,fileNameLength);

    for(int i=0;i<fileNameLength;i++)
        std::cout<<buf5[i];

    std::cout<<" "<<hasEncryptionHeader<<" "<<hasDataDescriptor; //testing

    fs.ignore(extraFieldLength+(hasEncryptionHeader?8:0)+size+(hasDataDescriptor?18:0)); //some of these values are for testing
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fs("zip file to read");

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) //this is for testing; i will check for the end of the zip file later
    {
        printNextFileName(fs);
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }

    fs.close();
}
```

This works for the simple zip file I made to test it, but it doesn't work for a jar file I found somewhere on my pc. I think the problem is that the code doesn't account for something before or after the file data. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own zip file extractor, for some reason? Because if not, there are many libraries available that will do the job for you, far more reliably than you can attempt on your own.

Comment: I'm trying to make a program that lists all the files in a zip archive. The only thing this program should do is ignore the rest of the file and read the file names (besides getting the file name lengths).

Comment: It didn't give any errors. It just didn't print anything to the console.

Comment: Thank you for the completed example. One thing that jumps out at me is NONE of the file IO is being checked. I'm now going to add some error checking and run a zip file through it and see what happens. Then I'll probably step through the function with a debugger. One thing to watch out for is sign extension. `int flags=buf[0]|buf[1]<<8;` and friends can blow up spectacularly if you read a byte from the file that is negative.

Comment: Durp. I'm slow today. File's not opened in binary mode.

Comment: I guess the person whom asked this question moved on with life 2 years ago. Anyhow, Wiki Zip File Format document pretty says that reading zip files from the beginning is undefined behaviour, since zip files are allowed to put anything they want at the front of the file. Such as Zip auto extract files which have executable code at the front. You should instead read the End of Central Directory structure at the back to determine file position of the local file headers you were trying to parse.

Comment: Infact you ignored the first 4 bytes which is the sig number, which would have been your red flag that you werent actually reading the local file header. The problem though with End Of Central Directory structure is that is variable length based on the fact that is has variable length comment. And Zip files put the comment length before the comment. Which means reading zip files is crappy. Unless you can assume that no comment is used in jar files.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1: File opened in text mode

When you read a file in text more all sorts of helpful conversions could be taking place that are most unhelpful when operating on a binary file. The most common is Windows carriage return and linefeed line endings (typically 0x0D0A) being converted to newline (typically 0x0A) or the reverse.

## Solution 1: Open the file in binary mode

```
std::ifstream fs("zip file to read", std::ios::binary);
```

## Problem 2: Sign Extension on Characters.

This simple program

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    char buf2[4] = {(char)0x80, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55};
    long size=buf2[0]|buf2[1]<<8|buf2[2]<<16|buf2[3]<<24;
    std::cout << std::hex << size;
    return 0;
}
```

should print out 55555580, right?

Nope. It can out ffffff80.

How?

When used in arithmetic `buf2[0]`'s 0x80 is converted to an `int` (or something larger if necessary) and if `char` is signed, the sign will be maintained. 0x80 is sign-extended into 0xFFFFFF80. And all those extra 1 bits wreck havoc on the binary operations as the `int` is assembled from the bytes.

Side note: See how I had to cast 0x80 to make it fit? The first sign that something is going to go wrong is often a cast.

## Solution 2

Use an `unsigned char`

```
int main() {
    unsigned char buf2[4] = {0x80, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55};
    // note that the cast isn't needed any more
    long size=buf2[0]|buf2[1]<<8|buf2[2]<<16|buf2[3]<<24;
    std::cout << std::hex << size;
    return 0;
}
```

or mask off the extended bits.

```cpp
int main() {
    char buf2[4] = {(char)0x80, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55};
    long size=buf2[0]     & 0x000000FF | 
              buf2[1]<<8  & 0x0000FF00 |
              buf2[2]<<16 & 0x00FF0000 |
              buf2[3]<<24 & 0xFF000000; 
    std::cout << std::hex << size;
    return 0;
}
```

note: long might not be 32 bit and you could still be walking into a world of hurt. Use the [Fixed Width Integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) from cstdint to make sure you are always working on data of the correct size when it matters. Here it matters.

Comment: You can set your `char`s to be unsigned by default in MSVC compiler flags. Very useful thing to do, really. Signed `char`s are almost **NEVER** useful.